# display figures on LYX

Tags: lyx, report

Am using Lyx to write report. I have to add some figures. But when compiling my file all the figuers are displayed on the top of the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the settings for the figure float (right click where it says *float: figure* -> settings) you can choose between a various float placements, see if changing that makes a difference.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279381/95229

Comment: Perfect , but i shoose 'here, if possible' (i use  a french edition)